# Сертификат ключа проверки электронной подписи ЕСИА

Tags: c#, авторизация, oauth, аутентификация

Добрый день!
Прикручиваю интеграцию ЕСИА к сайту. Все вроде работает, но хотелось бы проверять подпись у данных полученных от ЕСИА. Т.е. нужен сертификат самой ЕСИА (открытый ключ). А вот где его взять не понятно.

Comment: Saml или OAuth? В Saml-ответе в xml-е он есть, можете оттуда взять. А вообще вроде на госуслугах на странице, где управляете своими информационными системами скачать можно.

Comment: нужен открытый ключ ЕСИА для OAuth. Ключ, который возвращается в метеданных (https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/idp/shibboleth) у меня для OAuth не подходит. На странице управления своими информационными системами я вижу только свои ключи

Comment: OAuth сообщения вообще подписываются?

Comment: маркер доступа (access_token) содержит подпись: header.payload.signature. Вот именно эту подпись я и хочу проверить

Comment: @Shadow76 удалось решить проблему? Тоже OAuth подпись не проходит проверку.

Comment: У меня абсолютно такой же вопрос..
И как вы решили эту проблему? Вы получили сертификат с открытым ключом?

Comment: нет, проблему решить не удалось, открытый ключ я так и не получил.
Сейчас проект временно отложен (доступ к боевой ЕСИА не так просто получить)
Если получитсядостать открытый ключ, буду благодарен на информацию о способах решения этой проблемы

Answer (score 3):

В [методичке](http://minsvyaz.ru/uploaded/presentations/esiamr225_8AF82x5.pdf) страница 23:

- метаданные тестового поставщика идентификации ЕСИА опубликованы по ссылке
  https://esia-portal1.test.gosuslugi.ru/idp/shibboleth
- метаданные промышленного поставщика идентификации ЕСИА опубликованы по ссылке
  https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/idp/shibboleth

По этим ссылкам найдете сертификаты для тестового и боевого контуров.

Answer (score 0):

"В случае OpenID Connect при входе пользователя нужно проверять полученный ID Token. Структура токена описана в документе «Методические рекомендации по использованию ЕСИА». Актуальный сертификат ключей, используемых для подписи ID Token, Минкомсвязь не публикует, но его можно запросить, обратившись в техническую поддержку ЕСИА"

источник https://identityblitz.ru/products/esia-bridge/faq/

Answer (score 0):

В новой версии методички указано что можно [с сайта скачать](http://esia.gosuslugi.ru/public/esia.zip).

[В Методичке см. стр. 33](https://digital.gov.ru/ru/documents/6186/):

[image: скрин]